# Looking for solution to separate two app settings

Tags: usability, navigation, edit

I'm working on an app that converts a pdf into an embedable widget and has the following flow:

- user uploads pdf
- user sets title, description, other details
- user can customize the widget
- user publishes the document and gets a direct link or embed code

The app also has has an editor that allows users to edit the pdf and add links, images, videos to the pdf that will also show up in the widget. Maybe 20% of the users use the editor. Most people just upload the PDF, customize the title, description the widget settings and that's it.

I currently have a list of all the docs as cards on a "My docs" page and an "edit document" link for each that takes the user to the editor.

In the editor you can customize the widget settings along with the above mentioned features that most people don't use.

Also on the "My docs" page you can click on a document which opens a modal with the document details. Here you can edit the title, description in one tab, look at analytics details in another tab or get the embed code or direct link in a different tab.

I think the creation flow is ok. I'm looking for a simple solution for editing an existing document, both document settings (title, descrition, categories) and widget settings (bg color size etc). Seeing as not that many people use the editor, I don't want to take the users through that process for a background change in the widget.

How can I separate the widget settings from the editor without confusing my users? A solution I though of was to bring the widget settigns in the modal in a new tab. I'm also trying to go with a more linear flow and avoid doing the same thing in different places as it adds to the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

**Try showing your widget settings as an optional step in your flow.**

In the examples below I've put the widget settings as 'show advanced settings' (left) or 'advanced (optional)' (right).

Make sure you...

- Show the users the advanced settings are optional.
- Show the advanced settings with a lower visual impact (to not confuse users)
- Show the users they are now editing the basic settings.
- Show the users they can complete their task without having to edit the advanced settings.

You can do this by adding it to the label (see right example), hiding the option under a label (left example). In both cases the 'save' button is enabled which shows the user can save without advanced settings.

[image]

Comment: So these settings would go inside the modal like I suggested above?

Comment: Yes. That's what I would do.